# How can I show a specific page to admins only?

Tags: functions

I have a cart and shop page that I would only like to be accessed by admins. For the purposes of adding products and then using a share cart button to send to the consumer so that they may complete their purchase. I don't want them to then just "return" to shop or cart to view prices and items and things like that. How do I restrict the access of the Shop and Cart page to only admins without a plugin?

Comment: This is pretty unclear as a question but the short answer is to use `if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : //do your thang thang endif;`

Answer (score 0):

if not admin redirects to front page

try this function in the top of the file

```php
if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
  echo '<a href="'.home_url().'" id="notAdmin"></a>';
  echo '<script>document.getElementById("notAdmin").click();</script>';
}
```

Comment: Yes I have been researching this, but what actually goes into the brackets? Say the page class is woocommerce-cart?

Comment: I see your point, I had update the answer, and this works on my wordpress. just put this on the top of the file.

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't seem to work. I think it has to do with the .home_url(). In any case I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: whats the file name where you have test this code above?